# Is there any way to share the same dependencies in monorepo with yarn berry workspaces?

Tags: yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, yarn-berry

I'm currently building a monorepo with yarn berry.
So i've had to make a lot of many package.json to control the each of workspaces.
But i noticed there are too many the same dependencies in the each workspace, and if i want to update one of dependencies, i have to update many times unnecessarily.

So this is /package.json on the root level:

[image]

and this is /packages/button/packages.json:

[image]

As you can see, there are some of the same dependencies, so i'd like to share or extend the root one ( or other package.json )

Is there any way to do this?
If you help me out, it'd be a huge help :)